# spark cannot read from the aws

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My code in Python3, fails with the following error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load. :
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

The code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pyspark.sql.types import *
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--driver-memory 10g --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:6.5.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.1 pyspark-shell'
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").config(conf=SparkConf()).config("spark.local.‌​dir","/Users/psuresh
/spark_local_dir").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXX")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","XXXXXXXXXX")
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df= spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3a://a/b/c/d/dump/")
```

Comment: where are you running this code?

Comment: i am running this on python3. i have installed pyspark using pip3 install pyspark

Comment: @PruthviRaj You need JAR files to support reading from S3. Usually if you run in AWS those JARs are already present on classpath but since you are running it locally you'll need to add them using `--jars` flag in `spark-submit`

Comment: @kaysush i have added the jar files using os.environ

Comment: Then check logs if those artifacts are indeed getting downloaded and be put in classpath.